# Form-control broken after google chrome update

Tags: html, forms, google-chrome

I have some date fields in a form that send their inputs to the backend but after the latest chrome update the input never gets send. I tried this in Edge and Firefox, Mobile version of Chrome, and the same code works well, is there a work around for this?

This is how my code looks like, nothing special:

```
<input type="date" class="form-control" id="dr_start" name="dr_startDate">
```

If I remove the form-control it works, but it doesnt show the date picker and thats an issue for the users.

Comment: What's your exact Google Chrome version and on what operating system?

Comment: Is it the same error in incognito mode? Is it the same error with all extensions disabled?

Comment: What date picker implementation are you using? My Chrome shows a built-in date picker for <input type="date">

Comment: Version 65.0.3325.146 (Official Build) (64-bit), Windows 10, its not the same error in incognito, but i tried on a different computer in the office and its the same error.